# UI implementation query in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, math, user-interface

I am working in an application in that I need to record and play audio file. I have done everything related to recording and playing. This time I am little confused about UI related, May be first time this confusion.[image: Play back].

As per the above Image I need to show the playback track, so far I have done lot with progress bar and slider to show playback seconds or server response. I am checking my self to implemente this but I am not getting any exact idea to do. Can some suggest me any idea to implement the same. Your suggestions more useful for my work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enter the concept of **math,** especially the `sin()` and `cos()` trigonometric functions.

Comment: (Useful comment)Thanks for the quick response. I ll try in that prospect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the class I posted below and use it inbetween the background image and top it with the pause/play button. For the asset(little ring) at the current position you may want to use basic trigonometry.

A simple UIView subclass that draws a ring depending on a progress. It's may need some love by means of configuration of the circle radius and such:

**CircleProgressView.h**

```
@interface CircleProgressView : UIView
{
    double progress_;
    UIColor *color_;
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)progress;
- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color;


@end
```

**CircleProgressView.m**

```
@implementation CircleProgressView

- (void)setProgress:(float)progress
{
    _progress_ = progress;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    color_ = color;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color_.CGColor);
    CGContextAddArc(context,
                    self.frame.size.width / 2.0,
                    self.frame.size.height / 2.0,
                    self.frame.size.width / 2 - 4.5, 0.0, M_PI * progress_ * 2.0, NO);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```